# Limit of the sequence if the nth term is not given explicitly

Tags: real-analysis

$$\frac{1-2+3-4+\ldots+(-2n)}{{\sqrt{n^2+1}}        +\sqrt{n^2-1}}$$ I have to find out the limit of this sequence as $n$ tends to infinity and i am stuck. I can find limit if the nth term is given. But here i am not able to find that. Please help and thanks in advanc.

Comment: can you see why the numerator is equal to $-n$?

Comment: isn't the $n$'th term precisely what you have there?

Answer (score 4):

Notice that

$$\begin{align}S&=1-2+3-4+\dots+(-2n)\\+S&=\quad+1-2+3-\dots+(2n-1)-2n\\\hline2S&=1-1+1-1+\dots-1-2n=-2n\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$S=-n$$

So,

$$\frac{-n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2-1}}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^2}}+\sqrt{1-\frac1{n^2}}}$$

Can you take the limit from here?

Comment: Yes thank you very much

Comment: @user378334 No problem and I wish you a merry Christmas.

Comment: Same to you.Maths people are always busy let it be christmas or diwali.

Comment: @user378334 endlessly with the math is how I spend my holidays.

Comment: Which country do you belong?

Comment: America.  Enjoying my holidays by the warm computer fire.

Comment: Hey what is your real name.I wish i have a friend from foreign.Can we just become facebook friends.By the way i am vikrant from India

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50688/discussion-between-simple-art-and-user378334).

Comment: Oh the fact is i am new at this site.So i am not able to access the chat room option.

Comment: @user378334 Haha, I'm sorry I forgot.  I mean, I don't mind chatting with you, but I don't actually have social media.  This site is my social media.

Answer (score 2):

First notice that $1-2+3-4+\dots+(-2n) = -1 - 1 - \dots -1 = -n$. Now the fraction becomes $$\frac{-n}{{{\sqrt{n^2+1}}        +\sqrt{n^2-1}}} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}} + \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}} = f_n,$$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n = -\frac{1}{2}$.